# CloudWatch error in bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating a simple bash script that would routinely check mdadm and report back to CloudWatch with numeric values:

```
#!/bin/bash

## CHECKING RAID STATUS AND SUBMITTING RESULTS TO CLOUDWATCH ##
## 0 = Good, 1 = Bad, 2 = Still bad, needs investigating ##


HECK_RAID=`mdadm -D /dev/md1 | grep "State : [a-zA-Z]"`
SEND_RESPONSE=`aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name RAID-STATUS --namespace MONGODB --value "$STATUS" --dimensions InstanceID="$INSTANCEID" --region us-east-1`
INSTANCEID=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

if [[ $CHECK_RAID =~ [Cc]lean ]]; then
        STATUS=0
        $SEND_RESPONSE
elif [[ $CHECK_RAID =~ [Ff]ailed ]]; then
        STATUS=1
        $SEND_RESPONSE
else
        STATUS=2
        $SEND_RESPONSE
fi
```

Problem is, when I run the script to test, I get this:

> Invalid value ('') for param element of list:MetricData of type list

I know STATUS might be a culprit but is there a better way of creating the conditions I have made and actually submitting the results back to CloudWatch?

Comment: You want to run the command stored in variable `SEND_RESPONSE` ?

Comment: No, the command runs. But it spits back the error message i posted in the question. I'm trying to figure out what could possibly be wrong with the script

Comment: `SEND_RESPONSE` is only evaluated once, when you define it.

Comment: You reference `$STATUS` and `$INSTANCEID` in the command before they are defined. `$SEND_RESPONSE` will contain the output of the command, the command will not repeatedly run when you call the variable

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variable "HECK_RAID" instead of "CHECK_RAID".

Comment: Thanks for catching that.